# How to concurrently operate on rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a table called Task:

```
| ID | TASK    | Other columns... |
|  1 | ...     | ...              |
|  2 | ...     | ...              |
|  3 | ...     | ...              |
```

and I have a stored procedure that:

- Selects all available rows from the Task table
- Uses this data to do some work, such as updating other tables
- Deletes these rows from Task

This stored procedure will be invoked concurrently by a number of client applications. How can I have the stored procedure work on mutually exclusive rows? E.g.

- Tasks 1 and 2 are in the Task table
- Stored procedure is invoked and selects tasks 1 and 2 and begins process them
- Task 3 is added (stored procedure above is still running)
- Stored procedure is invoked again concurrently (previous stored procedure is not yet complete). This time the stored procedure should only select task 3.
- When either stored proecdure ends, it should delete the tasks it has worked on from the Task table

Comment: Read [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: Right now I have a solution that works, but it selects every row from the Task table. So in the scenario describe above. The first s-proc operates on tasks 1 and 2; the seconds s-proc operates on tasks 1, 2 and 3 (assuming the first s-proc has not deleted tasks 1 and 2 by the time the second s-proc starts)

Comment: If the table has thousands of tasks when the s-proc is run, I would prefer it to operate on all rows in one go, not one at a time - which I assume is the case with a queue?

Comment: Why would you want to invoke it from multiple clients?  Just let the thing run across all rows and SQL Server will use whatever processors are available.  It sounds like you're over-complicating things.  Just keep running it against eligible tasks until there's nothing left.

Comment: How would I invoke it? E.g. Client A inserts a number of tasks then calls the sproc. Then 6 hours later, Client B inserts more tasks and needs to invoke the sproc again.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to go with optimistic concurrency control approach. This is implemented by using timestamp column in sql server. Everytime a record is updated, timestamp value gets incremented automatically.

Whenever you are firing a select query you have to select Primary key column as well as timestamp column. Whenever you are updating this record your query should look like

```
UPDATE t SET Name = 'XYZ' from Employee t WHERE t.PrimaryKeyColumn = @Col1 
AND t.TimeStamp = @Timestamp

IF @@RowCount = 0
BEGIN
RAISEERROR('Record has been updated by another user',16, 1)
END
```

**Edit:**

Going with your question requirements

I can think of creating a global temporary table having additional column called SPID(connectionID) with default value as NULL

```
select *, NULL AS spId into ##TaskList
```

Key here is this global temp table will be available until the scope of process who created it. So you can use one permanent table for this task or keep the creator of temp table alive.

Since every stored proc will be running under different database connection hence all of them will be having unique SPID.

Any proc working on T1, T3 has to update it's SPID into this global temp table before starting its process on T1, T3.

Similary remaining proc will query ##TaskList to lock Tasks with SPID = NULL on which they want to work upon.

```
SELECT * FROM ##TaskList where SPID IS NULL
UPDATE SPID = @@SPID FROM ##TaskList where Task IN (T2, T4)
```

By this approach all the task will become mutually exclusive to stored procedure.

Comment: I agree that Optimistic Concurrency is better to use in general, for the specific case of getting records to process ('tasks') it does not work because all concurrent transactions pick the same record to process. The result is that there is always a conflict for all processors, except the first one that wins. For Optimistic Concurrent to work there has to be a low probability of conflict, it works great when the record being updated is basically random, but fail when the record being updated is deterministic (ie. everyone picks the 'next task').